# EF Core 5 Migration Creating Table Twice With Different Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit, Version 17.1.0 Preview 1.1), ASP .Net 5 Razor Pages (Non-MVC), EF Core 5 and SQL Server.

I have two classes, that have a many to many relationship.

Class 1 (Tag):

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Tag Description")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Narrative { get; set; }

    //Tags Have One Subject
    //Tag.SubjectId FK
    [ForeignKey("SubjectID")]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }

    //Tags Have One Or More Documents
    //(TagDocument Join Table)
    public List<TagDocument> TagDocuments { get; set; }

    //Tags Have One Or More Acronyms
    //TagAcronym Join Table
    public ICollection<Acronym> Acronyms { get; set; }
    public List<TagAcronym> TagAcronyms { get; set; }
}
```

Class 2 (Acronym):

```
 public class Acronym
 {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Display(Name = "Acronym")]
     [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Acronym cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
     public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Display(Name = "Description")]
     [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
     public string Description { get; set; }

     [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "URL cannot be longer than 250 characters.")]
     public string URL { get; set; }

     //Acronyms Have One Or More AcronymOld
     //AcronymOld.AcronymId (FK)
     public List<AcronymOld> AcronymsOld { get; set; }

     //Acronyms Have One Or More Tags
     //TagAcronym Join Table
     public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
     public List<TagAcronym> TagAcronyms { get; set; }
 }
```

Any Acronym can have many Tags, and a Tag can have many Acronyms.

I created a TagAcronym class to facilitate the creation of a Join Table in the database:

```
 public class TagAcronym
    {
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public Tag Tag { get; set; }

        public int AcronymId { get; set; }
        public Acronym Acronym { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I create the Migration it attempts to create a TagAcronym and an AcronymTag table for reasons I cannot understand.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "AcronymTag",
        columns: table => new
        {
            AcronymsId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
            TagsId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_AcronymTag", x => new { x.AcronymsId, x.TagsId });
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_AcronymTag_Acronym_AcronymsId",
                column: x => x.AcronymsId,
                principalTable: "Acronym",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_AcronymTag_Tag_TagsId",
                column: x => x.TagsId,
                principalTable: "Tag",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "TagAcronym",
        columns: table => new
        {
            TagId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
            AcronymId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_TagAcronym", x => new { x.TagId, x.AcronymId });
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_TagAcronym_Acronym_AcronymId",
                column: x => x.AcronymId,
                principalTable: "Acronym",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_TagAcronym_Tag_TagId",
                column: x => x.TagId,
                principalTable: "Tag",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_AcronymTag_TagsId",
        table: "AcronymTag",
        column: "TagsId");

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_TagAcronym_AcronymId",
        table: "TagAcronym",
        column: "AcronymId");
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The first thing I'd look at is that you appear to be making the relationship twice between your entities. A Tag has a `ICollection<Acronym>` property (and an acronym has a `ICollection<Tag>`) which EF will understand is a direct many:many and it will make middle man table for you to split it to two many:1 rels.. But you then also have each ent having a `List<TagAcronym>` so as well as letting EF help you by making its own middleman, youre also manually making your own middleman entity. Decide which way you want to work (hidden or visible middleman) and remove the other, and see what happens..

Comment: (Personally I would remove the `ICollection<Tag/Acronym>` props, flip the `List<TagAcronym>` to be an `ICollection` and init it to be a hashset rather than a list, and work with a visible middle man: `someTag.TagAcronym.Acronyms.Where(...)` vs `someTag.Acronyms.Where(...)` because I find that sooner or later, probably sooner, the boss wants something that means I need to be storing more data in the TagAcronym table..)

Comment: Could you include how the entities are configured in your context? Your entity setup is close to the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration), but something is a little off.

Comment: Yes , @CaiusJard Your explanation is very detailed and correct.

Comment: How are you configuring your many-many join? Or is everything being inferred by convention? IMHO define the relationship explicitly (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The relationship between Tag and Acronym are many to many so EF will automatically create a mapper table for these tables with name (TagAcronym or AcronymTag) so you dont need to explicitly specify TagAcroymn table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this model design  :

```
public class Tag
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Tag Description")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Narrative { get; set; }

        //Tags Have One Subject
        //Tag.SubjectId FK
        [ForeignKey("SubjectID")]
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public Subject Subject { get; set; }

        //Tags Have One Or More Documents
        //(TagDocument Join Table)
        public List<TagDocument> TagDocuments { get; set; }

        //Tags Have One Or More Acronyms
        //TagAcronym Join Table
        public List<TagAcronym> TagAcronyms { get; set; }
    }

public class Acronym
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Acronym")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Acronym cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "URL cannot be longer than 250 characters.")]
        public string URL { get; set; }

        //Acronyms Have One Or More AcronymOld
        //AcronymOld.AcronymId (FK)
        public List<AcronymOld> AcronymsOld { get; set; }

        //Acronyms Have One Or More Tags
        //TagAcronym Join Table
        
        public List<TagAcronym> TagAcronyms { get; set; }
    }
```

**datacontext**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            //Tag and Subject one-to-one
            modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>()
                .HasOne(b => b.Tag)
                .WithOne(i => i.Subject)
                .HasForeignKey<Tag>(b => b.SubjectId);
            //Tag and TagDocument one-to-many
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
                .HasMany(t => t.TagDocuments)
                .WithOne(g => g.Tag)
                .HasForeignKey(g => g.TagId);
            //Acronym and AcronymsOld one-to-many
            modelBuilder.Entity<Acronym>()
                .HasMany(t => t.AcronymsOld)
                .WithOne(g => g.Acronym)
                .HasForeignKey(g => g.AcronymId);

            //Acronym and Tag many-to-many
            modelBuilder.Entity<TagAcronym>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.TagId, t.AcronymId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TagAcronym>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
                .WithMany(p => p.TagAcronyms)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TagAcronym>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Acronym)
                .WithMany(t => t.TagAcronyms)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.AcronymId);

        }
```

[image]

You can refer to the official document：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many